# Two integrals with bounds

Tags: integration

I got an integral of the form:

$\int_0^\infty da(\int_c^a db f(b))$

Is it somehow possbile to make it possible to integrate first over a? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an integral over an infinite triangular wedge with one axis aligned with $a$. The region stays below the diagonal $b=a$. $$\int_c^\infty f(b) db \int_b^\infty da$$

Comment: The integral you give does not converge.